# How to fix this Selenium Error: bind() failed: Cannot assign requested address (99)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I've installed the latest version of selenium via Docker:

```
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
```

and then ran this in my python console:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
driver = webdriver.Remote("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub", DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
```

and finally checked the docker logs:

```
2019-04-24 19:09:26,880 INFO Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/selenium.conf" during parsing
2019-04-24 19:09:26,881 INFO supervisord started with pid 8
2019-04-24 19:09:27,865 INFO spawned: 'xvfb' with pid 11
2019-04-24 19:09:27,867 INFO spawned: 'selenium-standalone' with pid 12
19:09:28.038 INFO [GridLauncherV3.parse] - Selenium server version: 3.141.59, revision: e82be7d358
2019-04-24 19:09:28,039 INFO success: xvfb entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)
2019-04-24 19:09:28,039 INFO success: selenium-standalone entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)
19:09:28.093 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$3] - Launching a standalone Selenium Server on port 4444
2019-04-24 19:09:28.126:INFO::main: Logging initialized @247ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
19:09:28.289 INFO [WebDriverServlet.<init>] - Initialising WebDriverServlet
19:09:28.349 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Selenium Server is up and running on port 4444
19:09:43.631 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.apply] - Capabilities are: {
  "browserName": "chrome",
  "version": ""
}
19:09:43.633 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.lambda$apply$11] - Matched factory org.openqa.selenium.grid.session.remote.ServicedSession$Factory (provider: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
Starting ChromeDriver 74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}) on port 22103
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
[1556132983.659][SEVERE]: bind() failed: Cannot assign requested address (99)
19:09:44.266 INFO [ProtocolHandshake.createSession] - Detected dialect: OSS
19:09:44.490 INFO [RemoteSession$Factory.lambda$performHandshake$0] - Started new session cedc7067c0133f6492ff65dda5c7dd88 (org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
```

In particular, I'm unsure of how to fix this error:

```
[1556132983.659][SEVERE]: bind() failed: Cannot assign requested address (99)
```

I'm running this on my macbook pro using Mojave with the latest version of docker, python, and selenium. I also tried using other ports aside from 4444, same result. Thanks!

Comment: Hi,
I have the exact same issue.    
However, my tests are passing so I don't know what this error mean.    
Though, I'm unable to make parallel tests.
I hope we'll find a solution..

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: I am also facing same issue with Selenoid ... Still looking for solution

Answer (score 2):

We have seen that entry in the logs for a long time, however, there is no evidence it affects your tests. The message comes directly from ChromeDriver/Chrome. It is safe to ignore it.